# Office js custom formatting

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have written the following code to implement custom conditional formatting using Office JS -

```
function customFormatting() {
        // Run a batch operation against the Excel object model
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {

            // Create a proxy object for the active worksheet
            var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

            //Queue a command to write the sample data to the specified range
            //in the worksheet and bold the header row
            var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E9");

            var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
            conditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "red";
            conditionalFormat.custom.rule = {formula:">1001 && <5000"};

            //Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
            return ctx.sync();
        })
        .then(function () {
            app.showNotification("Success");
            console.log("Success!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Always be sure to catch any accumulated errors that bubble up from the Excel.run execution
            app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    }
```

I am getting the following error while running the code -

Error: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Answer (score 2):

(Revising my answer to describe 2 possible solutions, since I'm not clear on exactly which scenario matches what you're trying to achieve.)

**Solution 1: Highlight cell when cell value meets criteria**

In this first scenario, let's assume you have this table in the active worksheet, and your objective is to ***highlight the cell in column E*** of any row where the value in column E is between 1001 and 5000:

[image]

The following code uses conditional formatting to set fill color to yellow in column E when the cell value is between 1001 and 5000.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("E2:E9");

    var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    conditionalFormat.cellValue.format.fill.color = "yellow";
    conditionalFormat.cellValue.rule = { formula1: "=1001", formula2: "=5000", operator: "Between" };

    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            //app.showNotification("Success");
            console.log("Success!");
        })
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        //app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

After this code runs, the table looks like this:

[image]

**Solution 2: Highlight entire row when a specific cell value in the row meets criteria**

In this next scenario, let's assume you have this table in the active worksheet, and your objective is to ***highlight the entire row of data (columns A-E)*** whenever the value in column E of a row is between 1001 and 5000:

[image]

The following code uses conditional formatting to set fill color to yellow for the entire row of data (columns A-E), whenever the value in column E of a row is between 1001 and 5000.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E9");

    var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
    conditionalFormat.custom.format.fill.color = "yellow";
    conditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = '=IF((AND($E2>1001, $E2<5000)),TRUE)';

    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            //app.showNotification("Success");
            console.log("Success!");
        })
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        //app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

After this code runs, the table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I have implemented a use case with cell value formatting to filter the rows which are greater than 5000. I am trying to implement the same using custom formatting. Is it possible to do the same with custom formatting ?

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and it says that the property is read-only. 

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/master/reference/excel

Comment: Re your first comment -- I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Conditional formatting rules enable you to apply specified formatting (font, fill, color, etc.) to cells when specified conditions are met. for example, if you run the code that I posted, you'll see that it fills cells with the color "red" whenever cell value is > 1001 and < 5000. Conditional formatting rules will not "filter" rows.

Comment: I am trying to implement custom conditional formatting using Office JS.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not clear on precisely what you're trying to achieve. The sample code I posted above fixes the issues with the code you posted in your question, and fills cells with the color "red" whenever cell value is > 1001 and < 5000.  If you can clarify how what you're wanting to achieve differs from that scenario, I can try to help.  Is it that you're wanting to set fill color for *all* cellls in a row whenever the value in one of the cells in the row meets the criteria you specify?

Comment: @ArupamSengupta -- I've updated my answer to describe solutions for 2 different scenarios.  Hope this helps!  If this info resolves your issue, please mark the answer as "accepted" so that others may benefit from it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: This would be fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

conditionalFormat.custom.rule is read only. This means that you can't create an object and assign it to conditionalFormat.custom.rule as your code is trying to do. Instead you have to assign values to each property of the rule. For example:

```
conditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = '=IF(B8>INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0),TRUE)';
```

Note that the formula value has to be a valid Excel formula, not a JavaScript expression as you are using.